# Cannot Able to run App in iphone device after upgraded to Flutter 3.0

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio

After i upgraded to `flutter 3.0` i cannot able to run on iphone device and the error is showing in `xcode` is `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code` . Below is the error logs.

```
Unhandled exception:
Exception: Command "rsync -8 -av --delete --filter - .DS_Store /Users/mohammednabil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dqxqgayajktkkecyrvbsisfnqaux/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.framework /Users/mohammednabil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dqxqgayajktkkecyrvbsisfnqaux/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks" exited with code 23
#0      Context.runSync (file:///Users/mohammednabil/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:105:7)
#1      Context.embedFlutterFrameworks (file:///Users/mohammednabil/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:190:5)
#2      Context.run (file:///Users/mohammednabil/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:61:9)
#3      main (file:///Users/mohammednabil/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:17:5)
#4      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:32)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

> Android Studio Error logs

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/9j/h2_sjzh922d45b6rwp0bhjtc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.XdfRNz/flutter_ios_build_temp_diroT9KoZ/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```